# Are there any ways to speed up blender compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, performance

I have switched companies for a while, while in my last company we where using Fusion for compositing, in the new one we are using Blender.

I find it a bit hard to transition because of 2 main reasons:

1. The nodes look very messy because of all the squiggly lines and its sometimes hard to follow a path naturally.

The most important one:

2. Once you start adding a couple of nodes it becomes really slow, it seems to always be compositing something, if I move a node, it composites, if I make changes to a node that doesn't affect the final image, it composites. I like using the software but it can become very annoying.

Comment: It shouldn't composite if a node was only moved. It will if value in node's field was changed (if you made a field active and don't want to apply changes press `Esc`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You can change the lines to be straight by going to "File > User Preferences > Themes > Node Editor > Noodle Curving".

[image]

2. You can disable "Use Nodes" to keep it from updating until you are done moving.

[image]

Comment: Had no idea you can remove the noodles, life saver! Thanks

Answer (score 8):

To speed up things a bit you can tweak the performance options on the node editor (press <kbd>N</kbd> to make them visible on the right side of the screen).

[image]

Bring down the quality for edit, use OpenCL and adjust the chunksize.

Additionally you can use border rendering, to render only a small portion of the image (like you'd use the "region of interest" in fusion). On the UV/Image editor press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> and click and drag to draw a rectangle around the area you want to visualize. Blender will render only that area if the view border option is checked.

Use the node wrangler plugin, it has a lot of shortcuts to connect and replace nodes. Read this link for more info: http://gregzaal.github.io/node-wrangler/

Comment: I will add that node wrangler is included with Blender now :-)

Comment: thanks! I will give these options a try! Already using the node wrangler, really nice

Comment: The biggest drawback on using blender's compositor is that there is no way to preview the scene in real time. Blender does not have a playback buffer (like Fusion, Natron, nuke or even afterFX) So you only see what you are doing when you render....

Comment: @cegaton If Blender could get a playback buffer, it would be incredible. Would that be an appropriate feature request?

Comment: @AnsonSavage I would not hold my breath for that to be implemented any time soon. There are a number of specialized compositing apps available that do a much better job. Try using Fusion or Natron (both free) or even Nuke..